# How to Iterate over rows in PySpark grouped data

Tags: pyspark

My data format is like:

```py
| id | location |type |date      | time |
| -- | -------- | --- | -------- | ---- |
| 1  | 33       |out  |2020-11-03| 08:35|
| 1  | 34       |in   |2020-11-03| 08:37|
| 1  | 33       |in   |2020-11-03| 09:40|
| 1  | 33       |out  |2020-11-03| 10:35|
| 1  | 33       |in   |2020-11-03| 12:40|
| 1  | 33       |out  |2020-11-03| 18:35|
| 2  | 33       |out  |2020-11-03| 11:35|
| 2  | 33       |in   |2020-11-03| 18:35|
| 2  | 33       |both |2020-11-03| 20:35|
```

The logic:

1. group records by the same id, location and date
2. loop through the grouped records and find out the first "in" or "both" record and the corresponding time
3. loop through the rest records in the group to find out the next "out" or "both" record and the corresponding time
4. the "both" type could be "in" or "out". If no "in" records before the "both" record, then will regard this record as "in", and if there exists an unpaired "in" before, then will regard it as "out"
5. collect the paired records, and if there are 2 paired in and out in the same group, collect them as 2 rows

How can I realize it in Pyspark?

I worked out a script but it takes really long time in calculation. I guess there must be a more efficient method.

My code:

```
df is my sample data above

_intype = (in,both)
_outtype = (out,both)

lst = df.select("id", "location", "date").distinct().collect()

in_lst = []
out_lst = []
lst_agg = []
pre_type = None
for record in lst:
    id_val = record.id
    location_val = record.location
    date_val = record.date
    
    records = df.filter((df.id == id_val) & (df.location == location_val) & (df.date == date_val)).collect()
    for row in records:
        if pre_type == None or pre_type == 'OUT':
            if row.inout_type in _intype:
                time_in = row.transaction_time
                time_out = None
                pre_type = 'IN'
        elif pre_type == 'IN':
            if row.inout_type in _outtype:
                time_out = row.transaction_time
                pre_type = 'OUT'
    if time_out is not None:
        lst_agg.append((id_val, location_val, date_val, time_in, time_out))
        time_in = None
        time_out = None

df_agg_cols = ["id","location","date","time_in","time_out"]
df_agg = spark.createDataFrame(data=lst_agg, schema = df_agg_cols)
```

Expected output:

```
| id | location |date      | time_in |time_out|
| -- | -------- | -------- | ------- | ------ |
| 1  | 33       |2020-11-03| 09:40   |10:35   |
| 1  | 33       |2020-11-03| 12:40   |18:35   |
| 2  | 33       |2020-11-03| 18:35   |20:35   |
```

Comment: can you explain how you got this `| 1  | 33       |2020-11-03| 08:37   |10:35   |` record.. I see 08:37 is from another group `| 1  | 34       |in   |2020-11-03| 08:37|` ?

Comment: Oh sorry it is a typo when I copy data, the first in record time should be 09:40.

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated solution (2024-03-20):

This is a more complex solution using window functions. The logic is quite tailor-made for the short example you provided, so there might be corner cases this does not cover.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = spark.sql("""
               SELECT 1 id, 33 location, "out" type, CAST("2020-11-03" as date) date, "08:35" time UNION ALL 
               SELECT 1 id, 34 location, "in" type, CAST("2020-11-03" as date) date, "08:37" time UNION ALL 
               SELECT 1 id, 33 location, "in" type, CAST("2020-11-03" as date) date, "09:40" time UNION ALL 
               SELECT 1 id, 33 location, "out" type, CAST("2020-11-03" as date) date, "10:35" time UNION ALL 
               SELECT 1 id, 33 location, "in" type, CAST("2020-11-03" as date) date, "12:40" time UNION ALL 
               SELECT 1 id, 33 location, "out" type, CAST("2020-11-03" as date) date, "18:35" time UNION ALL 
               SELECT 2 id, 33 location, "out" type, CAST("2020-11-03" as date) date, "11:35" time UNION ALL 
               SELECT 2 id, 33 location, "in" type, CAST("2020-11-03" as date) date, "18:35" time UNION ALL 
               SELECT 2 id, 33 location, "both" type, CAST("2020-11-03" as date) date, "20:35" time
               """)


window_spec = Window.partitionBy(["id","location","date"]).orderBy("time") # for getting next/last types
window_spec_rolling = Window.partitionBy().orderBy(["id","location","date","time"]).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow) # for making a grouping id
grouping_ids_first = Window.partitionBy("grouping_id").orderBy("time") # for getting the first row in a group
grouping_ids_last = Window.partitionBy("grouping_id").orderBy(F.col("time").desc()) # for getting the last row in a group


df_base = (df
      .withColumn("last_type", F.lag("type").over(window_spec))
      .withColumn("next_type", F.lead("type").over(window_spec))
      .withColumn("grouping", 
                  F.when((F.col("type") == "out") & (F.col("last_type").isNull()),-1)
                  .when(F.col("last_type").isNull(),1)
                  .when(F.col("type") == F.col("last_type"),0)
                  .when(F.col("last_type") == "in",0)
                  .otherwise(1)
                 )
      .filter((F.col("grouping") != -1) & (F.coalesce("last_type","next_type").isNotNull())) # remove rows with -1 (group starts with out) or groups with just 1 row
      .withColumn("grouping_id", F.sum("grouping").over(window_spec_rolling))
      .withColumn("first_in_group", F.row_number().over(grouping_ids))
      .withColumn("last_in_group", F.row_number().over(grouping_ids_last))
     )

df_in = (df_base
         .select("id","location","date",F.col("time").alias("time_in"),"grouping_id")
         .filter("first_in_group == 1")
         )
      
df_out = (df_base
         .select(F.col("time").alias("time_out"),"grouping_id")
         .filter("last_in_group == 1")
         )

df_final = (df_in
            .join(df_out, on="grouping_id")
            .drop("grouping_id")
            )

df_final.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+--------+----------+-------+--------+
| id|location|      date|time_in|time_out|
+---+--------+----------+-------+--------+
|  1|      33|2020-11-03|  09:40|   10:35|
|  1|      33|2020-11-03|  12:40|   18:35|
|  2|      33|2020-11-03|  18:35|   20:35|
+---+--------+----------+-------+--------+
```

#### Initial solution (2024-03-14):

Here is a quick example based on your input that gets the desired output. Note, however, that it does not do the looping as you listed in your question. The solution is achieved by dividing the dataset into two (in and out), and then grouping and joining on the correct columns.

If this does not solve the question you have, please provide further example data, together with the expected output.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.sql("""
               SELECT 1 id, 33 location, "out" type, CAST("2020-11-03" as date) date, "08:35" time UNION ALL 
               SELECT 1 id, 33 location, "in" type, CAST("2020-11-03" as date) date, "08:37" time UNION ALL 
               SELECT 1 id, 33 location, "in" type, CAST("2020-11-03" as date) date, "09:40" time UNION ALL 
               SELECT 1 id, 33 location, "out" type, CAST("2020-11-03" as date) date, "10:35" time UNION ALL 
               SELECT 2 id, 33 location, "out" type, CAST("2020-11-03" as date) date, "11:35" time UNION ALL 
               SELECT 2 id, 33 location, "in" type, CAST("2020-11-03" as date) date, "18:35" time UNION ALL 
               SELECT 2 id, 33 location, "both" type, CAST("2020-11-03" as date) date, "20:35" time
               """)

df_in = (df
         .filter("type in ('in', 'both')")
         .groupBy("id","location","date")
         .agg(F.min("time").alias("time_in"))
         )

df_out = (df
         .filter("type in ('out', 'both')")
         .groupBy("id","location","date")
         .agg(F.max("time").alias("time_out"))
         )

df_final = (df_in
            .join(df_out, on=["id","location","date"])
            )

df_final.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+--------+----------+-------+--------+
| id|location|      date|time_in|time_out|
+---+--------+----------+-------+--------+
|  1|      33|2020-11-03|  08:37|   10:35|
|  2|      33|2020-11-03|  18:35|   20:35|
+---+--------+----------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks Kristo, I just updated my question to make it more clear. I want not only pair the first in record, but if some id has multiple in and out I could catch them all.

Comment: Thanks @Ellie, please see the updated solution and let me know if that solves it as you would expect.